# Sending Uin8array to Node Server but server receives an empty object instead of buffer

Tags: node.js, angular, express, httpclient

I'm trying to upload a blob audio along other data to a server, i have no problem with the other data but the blob is giving me a hard time,
Sending the object to server

```
$report(p:{report: THREE.Report, user: THREE.Employee, lang?: any}): Observable<any> {
    if(!p.lang) p.lang = this.userService.words.clang
    console.log("Report:", p)
    
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store`, p);
}
```

here's details about the object i am uploading: [image: THREE.Report]

Here's the data immediately before the post request is made, [image: p]

The data displayed when console.log is executed on req.body [image]

As seen, report.tick and report.audio are empty object, why is that and how do i make it work?

I have lost count of the different solutions i have tried

Answer (score 0):

I got it working and decided to share the solution (may not be optimal but it worked eventhough i did not send/receive a buffer but i got the audio blob )
I used FormData and content-type multipart/form-data as other examples suggested which worked when submitting only the blob but failed with the combined data. (came across so many errors and gained more knowledge) 
I then realised that submitting from a form in plain HTML never had such prob and then decided to use that, created a form dynamically, with one input(text) containing the JSON string generated from the object and another(file) for the blob
[image: THREE.windows]

```
$report(p:{report: THREE.Report, user: THREE.Employee, lang?: any}): Observable<any> {
    if(!p.lang) p.lang = this.userService.words.clang
    console.log("Report:", p)
    

    /* Creating Form Element  */
    let Sform = THREE.windows.document.createElement("form");
    Sform.setAttribute("method", "post");
    Sform.setAttribute("action", "");

 
    // Create an input element for JSON string
    let stext = THREE.windows.document.createElement("input");
    stext.setAttribute("type", "text");
    stext.setAttribute("name", "data");
    stext.setAttribute("value", JSON.stringify(p));
    
    Sform.append(stext);
    

    /* Done Creating Form Element  */

    let formdata = new FormData(Sform);
    formdata.append('audio', p.report.audio)

    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/store`, formdata);
  }
```

from the server-side i got [image: Server-Side],
Atleast now i finally got the blob.

ServerSide:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer({ dest: "upload" });

const app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: "*"
};

function control(x){
  var router = require("express").Router();
  router.post("/store", upload.single("audio"), (req, res)=>{
    console.log("FILES:",req.file);
    console.log("BODY", req.body);
  });

  x.use('/miniUrl', router);
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Up and active." });
});
control(app);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```